# haskell Not in scope: data constructor `ShowTree'

Tags: binary-tree

I'm trying to do an assignment where I draw a binary tree. I don't understand how to get rid of the error "not in scope: data constructor.

```
data BinTree a = Node a (BinTree a) (BinTree a) | Emp
deriving (Show)

hyp :: [String] -> [String]
hyp = map ("--" ++)

showTree :: Show a => BinTree a -> [String] 
showTree Emp = []
showTree Node p left right = show p ++ newl ++ hyp (showTree left) ++ hyp (ShowTree     right) where newl = "\n"
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I didn't realize the last showTree was ShowTree instead of showTree. I fixed that but then I ran into another error: parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets) I don't understand why I am receiving that error. Can somebody explain it to me?

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue that raises the "not in scope: data constructor". The name of the constructor is conveniently described in the error message. As a first step, we need to do a case-sensitive search for ShowTree and replace it with showTree. This might help you proceed in the assignment.

```
ShowTree instead of showTree.
```

Once you fix the above typo, you will probably face a couple of issues before the program can run.

Update:
The parse error is because of the deriving indented correctly. Haskell, as in Python, whitespace is significant.

I moved the deriving(Show) in the same line as the data constructor.

```
data BinTree a = Node a (BinTree a) (BinTree a) | Emp deriving (Show)
```

That should probably help you get going. Once you fix that, you will probably face this error:

```
Couldn't match type `Char' with `[Char]'
Expected type: [String]
  Actual type: [Char]
In the first argument of `(++)', namely `newl'
In the second argument of `(++)', namely
  `newl ++ hyp (showTree left) ++ hyp (showTree right)'
```

The above error indicates that the expected type was a list of Strings where as a list of chars is being passed (so one string). Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you provide some hints of where my mistakes are?

Comment: @user3399557 pls check the answer section for some additional hints.